# Relations Proof: Intersection of Two Sets of Path Length n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations

I am trying to answer the following question:

Prove that $(R \cap S)^{n} \subseteq (R^{n} \cap S^{n})$ for all $n\geq1$

---

### Attempt using Induction

**Base Step**

$(R \cap S)^{1} \subseteq (R^{1} \cap S^{1})$

$R \cap S \subseteq R \cap S$ *(obviously true)*

**Induction Assumption**

Assume that $(R \cap S)^{k} \subseteq (R^{k} \cap S^{k})$ for some arbitrary $k \geq 1$

**Prove for k+1**

$(R \cap S)^{k+1} \subseteq (R^{k+1} \cap S^{k+1})$

Here, I'm not sure where to use the our assumption that it is true for $n = k$

---

### Attempt Using Mathematical Logic

The relation $R^{n}$ on set A contains all $(a,b)$ such that $a R^{n} b$ for some $a \in A,b \in A$.

Similarly, the relation $S^{n}$ on set A contains all $(c,d)$ such that $c S^{n} d$ for some $c \in A,d \in A$.

$R\cap S$ on set A contains all $(e,f)$ such that $e R f$ and $e S f$  for some $e \in A,f \in A$.

How do I show what $(R\cap S)^{n}$ is, and prove it is a subset of $R^{n} \cap S^{n}$?

Comment: From $R \cap S \subseteq R$ follows $(R \cap S)^n \subseteq R^n$ and similarly from  $R \cap S \subseteq S$ follows $(R \cap S)^n \subseteq S^n$. Thus $(R \cap S)^n \subseteq R^n \cap S^n$.